# Customized calender in Angular5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to show calendar on my page. Calendar should display given dates as active and others should be disabled.
I don't want to display calendar as pop-up.

Can anyone please help on this?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [angular-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) or generate a calendar by yourself using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: How to generate using moment.js...can you please provide any demo link for this?